# How to restore rsync files when multiple sources are used?

Tags: rsync

To restore files in opposite direction copied by

```
rsync -rq /source /dest
```

can be done by reversing the source and destination like this

```
rsync -rq /dest /source
```

If multiple sources are given

```
rsync -rq /source1 /sources2 /dest
```

then how do you restore/sync in the reverse way.